# Failed to open OS X Installer

Tags: objective-c

My Mac's system can not open now . I removed whole disk image on it . And now it can not open it . The Apple Genius Bar staff have already help me to restore it . and then it will be okay soon.

Comment: And whats exactly your question when it will be okay soon?

Comment: The Apple Genius Bar staff gave a Installer to me. and it is well to install .   if you install the system by yourself , perhaps it is not be okay . so they have system image in local server . we don't have any image in local server , we only download from U.S server which is certainly slow